# IBM Watson Assistant: What should be done if one entity value exist in multiple entities

Tags: ibm-cloud, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

Let's imagine we are opening a restaurant. We use a chatbot to handle customer ordering and customer complaint.

Intent:
#order
#complain

Entity:
@food: burger, noodle, chicken
@compliantItem: service, burger, chicken, noodle

In this case, when a customer says "I want to order burger", Watson Assistant recognizes #order as intent (which is ok) and burger in both @food and @compliantItem category.

Is there a way to avoid it? Or should the entity values be reorganized?

Answer (score 0):

If you have items as part of several entities, then Watson Assistant has to (correctly) match them to all of those entities. You don't necessarily have to reorganize them, but to plan your dialog.

You should have dialog nodes reacting to either order or complaint. Then you could use slots to look for the required context. You need food for order and complaintItem for complaints. In each dialog, you probably want to check what exactly was entered.

Once the subnode with either intent or complaint has been processed, you return to the main level of your dialog tree.

Comment: As Henrik states, there is nothing wrong with having an item in multiple entity lists. However for maintenance if you have two lists that contain mostly the same values, it would make sense just to have the one list. If you combine an intent with an entity that makes any conditions unique. Or if you use entities in the response, then you can still use the one list. In he case here, I personally would have just the one entity list of @food, which can work with both the ordering and complaint intents.